# HTML5 - drawImage not drawing over other layer

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `drawImage` trying to draw tiles and a player. It works however it draws the player first *then* the tiles.  This should be the opposite because now I can't see my player.

How do I know my player is being drawn? Because if I take out what draws the tiles (`if (loadedImagesCount==NUM_OF_TILES) draw();`) then I can see my player. Also the message that says the player is drawn always pops up.

Help?

Here's my code:

```
// HTML5 JS Tile Example
var canvas, context, board, imageObj, tiles;
var currentMap = 1;
var upMap = 0;
var rightMap = 0;
var leftMap = 0;
var downMap = 3;
var NUM_OF_TILES = 16; // starting from ZERO

    var spawnX = 9; // spawn on X position
    var spawnY = 7; // spawn on Y position
    var playerImg = new Image();
    var currX = 9; // current X position
    var currY = 7; // current Y position

// Set return 2D array of map
function loadMap(map) {
    if (map == 1) {
        return [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ];
    }
}

var drawPlayer = function() {           
        realSpawnX = spawnX * 32;
        realSpawnY = spawnY * 32;
        playerImg.src = "me.gif";
        context.drawImage(playerImg, realSpawnX, realSpawnY, 32, 32);
        console.log("Player drawn at (" + spawnX + "," + spawnY + ") Real spawn: X: " + realSpawnX + " Y: " + realSpawnY);
}


window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    imageObj = new Image();
    tiles = [];
    board = loadMap(1);

    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 352;

    // Draw the player .,.. now
    drawPlayer();

    var draw = function() {
        var theX;
        var theY;
        // 3. DRAW MAP BY ROWS AND COLS
        for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {

                theX = x * 32;
                theY = y * 32;
                context.drawImage(tiles[board[x][y]], theY, theX, 32, 32);
            }
        }
    } 

    var loadedImagesCount = 0;

    // 2. SET UP THE MAP TILES

    for (x = 0; x <= NUM_OF_TILES; x++) {
        var imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
        imageObj.src = "line_tile/t" + x + ".png";
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            loadedImagesCount++;
            if (loadedImagesCount==NUM_OF_TILES) draw();
        };
        tiles.push(imageObj);
    }


};
```

Comment: So put `drawPlayer` after the loop that draws the map.

Comment: I did that robertc. I put `drawPlayer();` after the `for()` loop for drawing the tiles... outcome? Same thing.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to reflect what you've tried?

Comment: I just tried putting `drawPlayer();` in different places of the code. Nothign special.

Comment: Did you put it on the second last line before the `};` one?

Comment: You mean inside the for()? No. Outside? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I meant, it should be obvious where I've made changes:

```
// HTML5 JS Tile Example
var canvas, context, board, imageObj, tiles;
var currentMap = 1;
var upMap = 0;
var rightMap = 0;
var leftMap = 0;
var downMap = 3;
var NUM_OF_TILES = 16; // starting from ZERO

    var spawnX = 9; // spawn on X position
    var spawnY = 7; // spawn on Y position
    var playerImg = new Image();
    var currX = 9; // current X position
    var currY = 7; // current Y position

// Set return 2D array of map
function loadMap(map) {
    if (map == 1) {
        return [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ];
    }
}

var drawPlayer = function() {           
        realSpawnX = spawnX * 32;
        realSpawnY = spawnY * 32;
        playerImg.src = "me.gif";
        context.drawImage(playerImg, realSpawnX, realSpawnY, 32, 32);
        console.log("Player drawn at (" + spawnX + "," + spawnY + ") Real spawn: X: " + realSpawnX + " Y: " + realSpawnY);
}


window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    imageObj = new Image();
    tiles = [];
    board = loadMap(1);

    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 352;

    // Draw the player .,.. now
    //*************No, later

    var draw = function() {
        var theX;
        var theY;
        // 3. DRAW MAP BY ROWS AND COLS
        for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {

                theX = x * 32;
                theY = y * 32;
                context.drawImage(tiles[board[x][y]], theY, theX, 32, 32);
            }
        }
    } 

    var loadedImagesCount = 0;

    // 2. SET UP THE MAP TILES

    for (x = 0; x <= NUM_OF_TILES; x++) {
        var imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
        imageObj.src = "line_tile/t" + x + ".png";
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            loadedImagesCount++;
            if (loadedImagesCount==NUM_OF_TILES) {
                draw();
                drawPlayer();
            }
        };
        tiles.push(imageObj);
    }
};
```

The problem was that tiles were being drawn in an `onload` event - that executes when the browser has finished fetching the images from the network.  So no matter where you put the call to `drawPlayer` if it took anything over a millisecond or so to load all the tile images they would be getting drawn last.  The solution was to expand the block of code in the `onload` handler where it tested to see if all the images were loaded (this bit: `if (loadedImagesCount==NUM_OF_TILES)` ) so that you could then draw the map and the player in order.

Comment: Right. That's what I tried. The tiles still paint over the player. :\

Comment: @weka I've added some explanation to the answer